# Extended permissions - after set acl, group cannot write

Tags: debian, permissions, directory-structure, acl

I want to use **setfacl** to set permissions to `dir` for the users group.
I do something like this:

```
mkdir /Employee
chgrp employeers /Employee
setfacl -m d:g::rwx /Employee
```

And now, when I try to create a file (from users, who's memeber of this group) I get an error about 'No permission'.

```
root@debian:~# ls -la /Employee
all 8
drwxr-xr-x+  2 root employeers 4096 maj 21 14:50 .
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root       4096 maj 21 14:50 ..
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post a `getfacl /Employee` as well as the actual error you're getting?

Comment: Did you use exactly that order of commands? With `setfacl` I've observed cases where the order of commands mattered, e.g. if `chmod` was run after `setfacl` then what one might expect the `chmod` to have done will not apply. So we need the `getfacl` as Bratchley indicates.

Answer (score 1):

`d` is an abbreviation for `default`.  The default and actual permissions are independent.  Run the setfacl command a second time without the `d:`, then the permissions should work as desired.  I assume you want the effect of both commands.

The output of `getfacl` can suggest this conclusion to you, by

1. showing `default:` expanded
2. showing the original Access Control Entries which do not contain "default", indicating that there is something different about the entry you made.

In turn, the `+` in the output of `ls -l`, shows that there are ACE's, which permit accesses not otherwise expected from the basic mode (there is no way standard POSIX ACE's can deny an accesses permitted by the basic mode you see)[1].  After the second setfacl command, you will notice that the basic mode changes to `rwxrwxr-x`.  This is because `employeers` is the primary group of the file, and setfacl avoids creating a duplicate entry.

---

[1] Windows and NFSv4 ACLs allow deny entries. Many consider this to be a complexity trap, including the manpage for nfs4_acl. Naturally this means ACL order is significant. Apparently Windows GUIs change them to a "preferred" order with explicit deny entries first, and inherited entries at the end.